# Android selecting layout-large?

Tags: android, layout, grid

I am building an Android app and for large screens I want to populate a 6x6 grid with images; on smaller screens I want to populate a 4x4 grid.  My problem is that, in code, I need to know if the screen is layout-large or bigger - to populate the grid appropriately.

So, how can I tell if Android is selecting layout-large or not?

Answer (score 2):

Well you might consider setting things up so that your grid just fills up regardless of size, but short answer:

```
  getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
```

Note that the above API call is for Honeycomb or newer.  If you're targeting older than that you'll have to use:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_LARGE;
```

See [the docs on `Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) for more.